# При скачивании файла pdf, к его названию присваивалось имя техники которую выбрал пользователь

Tags: php, html, laravel

коллеги. Не получается присвоить к переменной название выбранной пользователем техники. То есть, клиент заполняет форму, при её заполнение и нажатию на кнопку он получает файл pdf с названием техники и её характеристикой. Как можно реализовать то, чтобы название техники присваивалось к переменной $filename, которая находится по коду в самом низу, и скаченный файл имел название выбранной техники.
Сайт лежит на хостинге с подключенной бд, в реализации использовался PHP Laravel
Название техники подтягивается из БД
<?php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;



use App\Exceptions\Warning;

use App\Import\MachineImport;

use App\Model\Machine;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use App\Exports\MachineExport;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;





trait MachineOrderTait

{

    protected function getPhotoUrl($file, $defaultImage = '' ) {

        $file_content = false;

        if ($file) {

            return $file;

            // $file_content = @file_get_contents($file);

        }

        if (!$file_content) {

            $file = resource_path('img').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$defaultImage;

            $file_content = @file_get_contents($file);

        }

        $imageData = base64_encode($file_content);

        $mime_type = 'image/png';

        if (strpos($file, '.gif') !== false) {

            $mime_type = 'image/gif';

        }

        if (strpos($file, '.jpeg') !== false || strpos($file, '.jpg') !== false) {

            $mime_type = 'image/jpeg';

        }



        return 'data:'.$mime_type.';base64,'.$imageData;

    }

    public function createOrder()

    {

        ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "5000000");

        $Machine = Machine::findOrFail($this->request->id);



        $EUR_2_RUB = $this->getEuroRate();



        if ($EUR_2_RUB) {

            $Machine->price = number_format($EUR_2_RUB * $Machine->price, 0,'.', ' ').' ₽';

        }



        $options = DB::select("

                                select 

                                  option_id,

                                  value,

                                  mo.name,

                                  mo.description

                                from machine_option_value ov

                                join machine_options mo on mo.id = ov.option_id 

                                where ov.machine_id = :id and ov.value != '' and ov.value is not null ", ["id" => $Machine->id]);



        $optionCode = DB::select("select * from machine_option_code");



        foreach ($options as &$option) {

            $t = $option->value;



            foreach ($optionCode as $item) {

                $optionPrice = number_format($EUR_2_RUB * $item->price, 0,'.', ' ').' ₽';

                $t = str_replace(trim($item->code), $optionPrice, $t);

            }



            $m = [];

            preg_match_all('/(\d{1,})\s{0,1}€/', $t, $m);

            foreach ($m[0] as $idx => $subStr) {

                $val = $m[1][$idx];

                $newVal = number_format($EUR_2_RUB * $val, 0,'.', ' ').' ₽';

                $t = str_replace($subStr, $newVal, $t);

            }

            $option->value = $t;

        }





        $filter = $this->request->filter;

        $Machine->q0 = Machine::calcQ0($Machine, $filter['t0'], $filter['tc'] );

        $Machine->p = Machine::calcP($Machine, $filter['t0'], $filter['tc'] );

        $Machine->link_photo_main = $this->getPhotoUrl($Machine->link_photo_main, 'machine-main.jpg');

        $Machine->link_photo_dimensions = $this->getPhotoUrl($Machine->link_photo_dimensions, 'machine-dimensions.jpg');



        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

        $css = file_get_contents(resource_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'css' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'order.css');

        $html = view('order', ['machine' => $Machine, 'filter' => $filter, 'options' => $options])->toHtml();

        $header = view('order_header')->toHtml();

        $footer = view('order_footer')->toHtml();

        $mpdf->margin_header = 0;

        $mpdf->margin_footer = 0;

        $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);

        $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

        $mpdf->AddPageByArray([

            'margin-left' => 0,

            'margin-right' => 0,

            'margin-top' => 20,

            'margin-bottom' => 20,

        ]);





        $mpdf->WriteHTML($css, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

        $fileName = 'commercial.pdf';

        $mpdf->Output($fileName, \Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, откуда берется название техники, но если из шаблона, то его можно передать ajax-ом на сервер и там уже вытянуть в свою php-переменную

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помог мне товарищ, перед foreach я присвоил к $filename значение 'name' из базы данных, так же добавил '.pdf'